# Rails: Ordering in nested form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-attributes

I have a profile model that accept experience model as a nested attributes, and i want to order experience by experience_end_date this is my profile model

```
has_many :experiences, dependent: :destroy, :order => ("experience_end_date")
accepts_nested_attributes_for :experiences
```

but this is don't work can some one help in how can i fix this?

the experience_end_date is a date field column in the experience model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you specify the order:

```
has_many :experiences,
         ->{ order(:experience_end_date) },
         dependent: :destroy
```

That will sort by ascending; for descending do this:

```
has_many :experiences,
         ->{ order("experience_end_date DESC") },
         dependent: :destroy
```

You can usually find answers to such questions in the [documentation](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/has_many), either in explanations or in the example code snippets.

Comment: this is working but how can i order by DESC experience_end_date i have tried ->{ order(:experience_end_date DESC ) } but it is a bad solution

Comment: Mark my response as the answer, if it correctly answered your question.